# Cannot list pipeline steps using AzureML CLI

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to list steps in a pipeline using AzureML CLI extension, but get an error:

```
>az ml run list -g <group> -w <workspace> --pipeline-run-id 00886abe-3f4e-4412-aec3-584e8c991665
UserErrorException:
        Message: Cannot specify ['--last'] for pipeline runs
        InnerException None
        ErrorResponse
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UserError",
        "message": "Cannot specify ['--last'] for pipeline runs"
    }
}
```

From help it looks like `--last` option takes the default value 10 despite the fact that it is not supported for the `--pipeline-run-id`. How the latter is supposed to work?

Comment: `last_n` does not work with Pipelines. We will update the documentation and the error message.

`az ml pipeline list-steps --run-id` should work to list the steps in a pipeline.

Comment: `>az ml pipeline list-steps -g <group> -w ,workspace> --run 00886abe-3f4e-4412-aec3-584e8c991665
'Run' object has no attribute '_is_reused'`

Comment: Usually that type of error means there is some mismatch in package versions, and it’s getting a generic Run instead of StepRun/PipelineRun. Can you confirm you have the latest SDK version all around.